# What is the proper word for a Sidebar

Tags: vocabulaire, informatique

I'm working in web development and want to tell my users to go look for an item in the sidebar.

Google translate returns me "Barre latérale" but, as a French speaker, that doesn't feel right to me.

Just like a header is "une entête", is there a proper way to say "a sidebar" in French?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word reference has pulled up these results:

- ***encadré*** (for a webpage)

http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/sidebar

This word can also be seen in popular use here: http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/sidebar.html

Comment: Still doesnt feel right, but the reference seems good... So I guess it is "Encadré"

Comment: This link may help you narrow down what feels right. http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/sidebar.html

Comment: I wouldn’t use “encadré” if the sidebar is not actually boxed.

Comment: I saw 'volet' as a possibility.  Thoughts on this?

Answer (score 5):

I'd say *un menu latéral*, if looks somewhat like a menu.
But it seems that *barre latérale*, which sounds maybe more like a toolbar, is nevertheless the most common name for a sidebar.

Comment: As a developer I would understand "menu latéral" while I would not feel sure of my understanding of "encadré". To me it is best to keep it untranslated though ("*il faut qu'il y ait un lien vers la home page dans la sidebar*"): even though this is actually bad French, this is not ambiguous on a technical standpoint.

Answer (score 5):

If for some reason I wanted to avoid *barre latérale* or plain *sidebar*, I would probably use “*la barre de gauche/droite*”, though it loses some generality. If it needs to stay generic, why not “*le bloc latéral*”?

Or if you want to stay in the tone of *entête*, you can dig in publishing idiom and say *les marges*.

Or you could also specify the function of the bar, as in “*les flux latéraux*” or “*le menu latéral*”,